# Google Maps API: How to draw "curved" flight route polygon line between two markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there any easy way or additional API to draw a curved polygon line fitting to the map projection of the earth? I can only draw a normal line, but not a curved one.

Comment: see [the geodesic PolylineOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the `geodesic`-property of the `Polyline` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a great circle route because the earth is a sphere:https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080128153829AAJPuku. It appears automatically curved:http://nationalatlas.gov/articles/mapping/IMAGES/2mercators.gif.